# VB.NET Convert String to Int throws error : Input String was not in a correct format

Tags: vb.net

I am using **.NET Framework 1.0** and I try to convert String to int but throws an error ***Input String was not in a correct format***

Take a look at my code

```
Dim Total As Integer
Total = (Convert.ToInt32(Me.lblOldQty.Text)) - (Convert.ToInt32(Me.txtQty.Text))
Dim Value As String = Me.lblOldQty.Text + " - " + Me.txtQty.Text + " = " + Convert.ToString(Total)
Me.lblNewValue.Text = Value
```

I already tried using ***CInt and Integer.Parse*** but same result.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to ask yourself: *"What is an [integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)?"* Once you know the answer to this question you'll know why this error is thrown on form load: **An empty string is not an integer!**

Comment: Also see [String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Its .Net 2.0. Maybe you should use .Net 2.0 or supply a similar function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Dim Total As Integer
Total = Integer.Parse(lblOldQty.Text) - Integer.Parse(txtQty.Text)
Dim Value As String = lblOldQty.Text + " - " + txtQty.Text + " = " + Convert.ToString(Total)
lblNewValue.Text = Value
```

Use breakpoint while execution and check if values are passing correctly to `lblOldQty.Text` and `txtQty.Text`

Comment: You should use `TryParse` to avoid exceptions for invalid values.

Comment: still receive an error right after i open the form.

Comment: @xxbbcc : hi, can you teach me on how to use TryParse command?

Comment: Did you used breakpoint and checked what values you are getting ?

Comment: The error comes from this line `Total = Integer.Parse(lblOldQty.Text) - Integer.Parse(txtQty.Text)` and I am pretty sure I got the right value from database.

Comment: Does **TryParse** command applicable in .Net framework 1.0 ? I am only getting **.Parse** in writing code.

Comment: Can you use `Total = Val(lblOldQty.Text) - Val(txtQty.Text)`?

Comment: @Insane : `Total = Val(lblOldQty.Text) - Val(txtQty.Text)` that works sir. thank you very much

Comment: TryParse was introduced in .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim OldQty, Qty, Total As Integer
If Int32.TryParse(Me.lblOldQty.Text, OldQty) AndAlso Int32.TryParse(Me.txtQty.Text, Qty) Then
    Total = OldQty + Qty
End If
```